# PHP How to execute an http_build_query without using Location?

Tags: php, header, location

How do you even execute http_build_query? If I have the code:

```html
$data = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'boom', 'cow' => 'milk', 'php' =>'hypertext processor'); 

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n"; 
echo http_build_query($data, 'myvar_');
```

Then that's great. But after the user has clicked on a button (using a href?) and the http_build_query has been created/updated, how does one make php direct them to the url?

I've read a lot on http_build_query, and searched the whole day. I can't use Header Location: etc because I'll loose my session variables. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why would you lose your session variables? if you call session_start at the top of that target php page, the session variables will be accessible.

Comment: Well, they may be working. I cannot tell because all my links are currently href's, each with their own query appended to the end. e.g. `http://www.example.com/index.php?SortProduct=TV` and the next href will be `Sortprices=ASC`. What I want to do is build a query e.g. `SortProduct=TV` and then be able to toggle the second query parameter based on the user click. That could be `http://www.example.com/index.php?SortProduct=TV&Sortprices=ASC` or `http://www.example.com/index.php?SortProduct=TV&SortBrands=LG`. Once the query string is built, I need to direct the user to that http_build_query.